# Facing issue in QEMU on android cuttlefish

Tags: android, android-source, qemu

Trying to bring up Android cuttlefish from QEMU.
Successfully launched android cuttlefish from QEMU In x86 processor Ubuntu and got Android UI in vysor (tool) app. Facing problems with ARM64 processor to launch Android cuttlefish UI using QEMU.

$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version

QEMU emulator version 7.2.0 (Debian 1:7.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.3)
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

Please find snipped logs :

############################################################################

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64
2023-10-17T08:47:28.314434Z qemu-system-aarch64: host does not support in-kernel GICv3 emulation
Detected unexpected exit of monitored subprocess /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64
Subprocess /usr/bin/qemu-system-aarch64 (8986) has exited with exit code 1
failed to read from socket, retry.
Start modem simulator, server_fds: 64, Sim type: normal
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:7200
Metrics started
Metrics host received: VMStart
Metrics message failed: [
�ݟ��12X

��������*�
     ��������(26.2.0-1014-raspi8"@RGOOGLE212306767512169342437 ݟ� 
�1*CUTTLEFISH_METRICS]
http error code: 0
curl error code: 6 | Couldn't resolve host name
Message failed to send to ClearCut: VMStart
android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-virtualization-grpc-server E 10-17 08:47:28  
8984  9012 GarageModeServerSideHandler.cpp:131] operator(): marker file /home/****/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/power_state has not been created yet.
Size of OBJECT = 1204
Size of components in TPMT_SENSITIVE = 744
TPMI_ALG_PUBLIC                 2
TPM2B_AUTH                      50
TPM2B_DIGEST                    50
TPMU_SENSITIVE_COMPOSITE        642
MAX_CONTEXT_SIZE can be reduced to 1264 (1344)
transport message failed, response body:
transport message failed, response body: 

#########################################################################
```

I could not understand how to overcome this issue. Could you please help(clue) me resolve this issue?

Comment: "host does not support in-kernel GICv3 emulation" suggests an issue with your host hardware. What host machine are you running this on ?

Comment: I have install ubuntu OS in raspberrypi4 B (ARM64 processor). Is it possible to bring up GICv3 emulation in the device. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is this error:

> 2023-10-17T08:47:28.314434Z qemu-system-aarch64: host does not support in-kernel GICv3 emulation

This means that the host machine you're using (a raspberry pi 4B) does not have version 3 of the GIC interrupt controller. In order to show the guest VM a GICv3 interrupt controller, the host must have one: when it does not, KVM/QEMU will report this error.

There are only two options:

- if the virtual machine type supports giving the guest a GICv2, that would work. However, I don't know if the Android cuttlefish board type supports this.
- use a different host machine which does have a GICv3.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I know how to check device will support GICv3. Tried this command "zgrep 'CONFIG_ARM_GIC_VERSION' /proc/config.gz" Is this the way to check. do you have any idea?

Comment: No, that only checks whether the kernel will support a GICv3 if it is present. You need to know about the actual features of the hardware, for which purpose you need to look at spec sheets and so on.